# combing querySelector() methods

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code like this:

```
    document.querySelector('.wrap').style.height= lato;
    document.querySelector('.wrap').style.width= lato;
```

What's the syntax to combine the two objects in one?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you're asking. What two objects? If you are talking about not having to traverse the DOM twice to access the same element, I'd suggest caching the element after it is first accessed:

```
var wrap = wrap || document.querySelector('.wrap');
```

The first reference to `wrap` will ensure its value is assigned with `document.querySelector()`, and subsequent references will use the cached version.

```
wrap.style.height = lato; //Navigates through the DOM to find the element
wrap.style.width = lato; //Element is now cached, no DOM traversing needed!
```

Answer (score 1):

There actually *was* (still is) a syntax **designed** for this exact purpose or not having to type the selector twice or save it into a variable but people don't use it because it has a lot of other issues:

```
with(document.querySelector('.wrap')){ // don't actually do this :D
    style.height = lato;
    style.width = lato; 
    // ... all other changes
}
```

That's very frowned upon though, idiomatic DOM manipulation would simply cache it into a variable and call it twice saying explicitness is good here.

Comment: so you think calling it twice is the best option ?

Comment: @maioman I think caching it to a variable is the best option if you do not want to mimic what libraries like jQuey do.

Comment: performance-wise, targeting .cssText has any downfalls if compared to style.height

Comment: @maioman you should not care about performance in these scenarios. Using `.cssText` has the pitfall that it will override any other existing style assigned which makes it not worth it imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cssText:

```
document.querySelector('.wrap')
      .cssText = "height: "+lato+"; width: " + lato + ";";
```